# Is every simple function on a compact measure space the pointwise limit of continuous functions?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> **Question:** Let $(X,\mu)$ be a measure space and suppose that $X$ is compact. Is every simple measurable function $s:X\to\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. $s(X)$ is a finite set) the pointwise limit of continuous functions $f_n:X\to\mathbb{R}$?

**Edit**: Actually the answer is no! Thanks to David Mitra for the counterexample. But the question bellow still holds. **End Edit.**

I am asking this question in order to understand a proof in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis (p. 102). He defines a function $g:[-\pi,\pi]\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$g(t)=\begin{cases}1 &; D_n(t)\geq 0 \\ -1 &;D_n(t)<0,\end{cases}$$
where
$$D_n(t)=\sum_{k=-n}^ne^{ikt}.$$
He then says (without any explanation) that there are continuous functions $f_k:[-\pi,\pi]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $-1\leq f_j\leq 1$ and $f_j(t)\to g(t)$ for every $t$, as $j\to\infty$.

After some work, I found a way to convince myself that this is true, but I don't find it obvious at all. Since Rudin doesn't give any explanation, this must be very obvious and there should be something that I missed.

To prove it, I first used Uryshon's Lemma to obtain continuous functions $f_j$ such that
$$D_n^{-1}([0,\infty))\prec f_j\prec D_n^{-1}((-1/j,\infty)).$$
The limit of these functions is $\chi_{D_n^{-1}([0,\infty))}$ and by making a translation and a scaling, we are done.

> **Question:** How would YOU prove it?

Comment: No. With Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, the characteristic function of $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$ is not the pointwise limit of continuous functions. (A pointwise limit of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ is a *Baire class one function*; one can show such a function is continuous at each point of a dense subset of $[a,b]$.)

Comment: Ok thank you @DavidMitra !

Comment: @DavidMitra just a suggestion, why not post this as an answer?

Comment: @OP: Your construction is fine, I don't think there is a much simpler way. Just one comment why the construction is possible in this case: The set where $D_n (t) < 0$ is open. Hence, we don't just have **some measurable** set/function, but a very particular one.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is no.

A real-valued function $f$ on $[a,b]$ is called a [Baire class one function](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FBaire_function&ei=DXO7VMKEJYKpNsnBgaAB&usg=AFQjCNEysM4vSu1nvXHeqyL4gQw4VJk36w&bvm=bv.83829542,d.eXY) if it is the pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions from $[a,b]$.  It is known that a Baire class one function has many points of continuity; in fact, the set of continuity points of a Baire class one function on $[a,b]$ is dense in $[a,b]$ (an even stronger statement can be made). See [this MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32033/points-of-continuity-of-baire-class-one-functions) post for references.

So, easy counterexamples can be made. For instance, on $[0,1]$, the characteristic function of $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$ is not Baire class one.  It is a Lebesgue measurable simple function, of course).